How to get the page title from the alias?
Is there an API to find the title of a page using only its alias ?
I managed to get the internal path with this code (although the multilingual part doesn't feel the easiest option):
/**
 * Function to resolve an alias and find the internal path, considering language prefixes.
 */
function get_internal_path_from_alias($alias) {
  $language_manager = \Drupal::service('language_manager');

  // Check if the alias starts with a language code prefix (e.g., /fr, /en, /de).
  // Get all languages on the site.
  $languages = $language_manager->getLanguages();
  $prefix_found = FALSE;

  // Loop through the languages to check if the alias contains a language prefix.
  foreach ($languages as $language) {
    $langcode = $language->getId();
    if (strpos($alias, '/' . $langcode) === 0) {
      // We found a language prefix, so remove it from the alias.
      $alias = substr($alias, strlen('/' . $langcode));
      $prefix_found = TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }

  // Get the alias manager service.
  $alias_manager = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager');

  // If no prefix is found, pass NULL for the language code (default).
  // If a prefix was found, pass the language code for the alias lookup.
  if ($prefix_found) {
    $path = $alias_manager->getPathByAlias($alias, $langcode);
  } else {
    $path = $alias_manager->getPathByAlias($alias);
  }

  // Return the resolved path (or NULL if not found).
  return $path;
}

But after that I'm not sure how to get the title of my internal path ?
Also my function doesn't work with views.
What API could I use for this ?

This question is similar to: How can I get the node ID from a path alias?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can try this for nodes:
$path = \Drupal::service('path_alias.manager')->getPathByAlias('/your/path/alias');
$pathArray = explode("/", $path);
$node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(end((array_values($pathArray))));
$nodeTitle = $node->getTitle();

Views of course, are a little trickier, but this is one approach that may work:
$routeProvider = \Drupal::service('router.route_provider');
$pathRoutePattern = $routeProvider->getRoutesByPattern('/your/path/alias');
$getAll = reset($pathRoutePattern->all());
$getDefaults = $getAll->getDefaults();
$viewId = $getDefaults['view_id'];
$displayId = $getDefaults['display_id'];

$view = \Drupal\views\Views::getView($viewId);
$view->setDisplay($displayId);
$viewTitle = $view->getTitle();

